# xsl template is overriding with xsl include

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to create some reusable templates while developing a html page for xml with xsl. But when I include the other xsl's, the main xsl template is getting overridden instead of adding it to it. please suggest.

Here is my xml,

```
<employee>
<address>
    <street>street1</street>
    <city>city1</city>
    <doornumber>1-23</doornumber>
    <pincode>123456</pincode>
</address>
<personalinfo>
    <name>testname1</name>
    <phone>999999999</phone>
    <dob>23-09-34</dob>
</personalinfo>
<remarks>
    <education>
        <name>testname2</name>
        <college>college1</college>
        <gpa>7.5</gpa>
    </education>
</remarks>

<data>
    <name>data1</name>
</data>
<data>
    <name>data2</name>
</data>
<data>
    <name>data3</name>
</data>
<data>
    <name>data4</name>
</data>
<data>
    <name>data5</name>
</data>
</employee>
```

Here is my main xsl,

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>College</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="personalinfo/name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="remarks/education/college"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/city"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<!-- <xsl:include href="test_include1.xsl" /> -->
<!-- <xsl:include href="test_include2.xsl" /> -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my test_include1.xsl,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="employee">

<table><tr>
    <th>data names</th></tr>
<xsl:for-each select="data">
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </td>
</tr>

</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my test_include2.xsl,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="employee">

<table><tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>College</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="personalinfo/name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="remarks/education/college"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to modularize the same xml data in different templates so that I can reuse the same templates in other stylesheets. Please suggest how I can acheive this. Thank you.
Here is the expected result,

```
     <html><body>
   <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>College</th>
        <th>City</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>testname1</td>
        <td>college1</td>
        <td>city1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr><th>data names</th></tr>
        <tr><td>data1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>data5</td></tr>
     </table>
     <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>College</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>testname1</td>
        <td>college1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: By using `xsl:include` the included templates will simply be added to the main XSLT as if they had been added manually by you. This will leave you with three templates matching `employee`, with equal priority, which is considered an error. (Some processors signal the error, others will just use the last one, as in your case). It's possible you need `xsl:import` instead, but it is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you edit your question to show your expected output? Thanks!

Comment: I have a huge xml where different parts of data to be created as multiple reusable templates. As and when I need it, I should be able to include it to the main xsl. I tried using xsl:import, but that is also overriding the templates with the same match. Is there any way to merge the templates with the same match without overriding?

Comment: If you want to process the same node with different templates then consider to use modes, there is also some support for applying an imported template in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#apply-imports.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Martin. I was able to achieve this with template modes. Would there be any performance impact if we use more template modes like around 10 in an xsl?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see any xsl:include declarations in any of these stylesheets, so I'm not quite sure what you are doing. [Sorry - missed the pale grey commented out code - poor contrast on my monitor.]

Secondly, with XSLT 1.0 the behaviour when you have two templates matching the same node, with the same precedence and priority, is not very well defined. Technically it's an error, but the processor is allowed to recover by choosing the rule that comes "last in the stylesheet" - which itself is not particularly well defined when there are multiple modules involved.

Thirdly, you say "the main xsl template is getting overridden instead of adding it to it". This suggests you have some particular expectation of how you want it to behave, but I can't really work out what this expectation is. You haven't given any expected results, so I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But it will always be the case, if you have more than one rule that matches a node, that you either get an error, or exactly one of the rules is executed - they are never combined in any way.

Comment: Hello Michael, I have added the expected output above. In summary, I have multiple stylesheets. So, trying to create multiple templates from the same xml to reuse in other stylesheets. I tried with <xsl:import> and <xsl:include> but didn't work as other templates are overiding due ot same match. Please suggest how I can achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by modes. 
Another way is to give each xsl:template match a priority number. The one which you want to get executed should have the highest priority. Priority is attribute of xsl:template

```
<xsl:template match = "employee" priority = "4"> do the task </xsl:template>
```